# Do repetitive ops on an STL Vector Allow "Inherent Parallelism"/Improved Memory Access?

Tags: c++, vector, parallel-processing, stl

I have a two phase process that constitutes a cycle in my simulation program.  More or less I have the following:

```
struct Coordinates
{
   double * x, * y, * z;
   uint * kind, count;
   double GetDist(const uint p1, const uint p2);
};

struct Polynomial
{
   double * A, * B;
   uint n1, n2;
   uint Flatten(const uint i, const uint j);
   double CalcResult(double distSq, uint kind1, uint kind2)
   {
      uint ij = Flatten(kind1, kind2);
      double base = B * distSq;
      return A[ij]*(pow(base,n2)-pow(base,n1));
   }
};
```

My question is if I write my code like

```
struct Model
{
   Coordinates c;
   Polynomial f;
   double DoTest()
   {
      double result = 0;
      uint count = 0;
      std::vector<double> distSq;
      for (uint i=0; i<c.count; i++)
      {
         for (uint j=i; j<c.count; j++)
         {
            result = c.GetDist(i,j);
            distSq.push_back(result);
         }
      }
      result = 0;
      for (uint i=0; i<c.count; i++)
      {
         for (uint j=i; j<c.count; j++)
         {
            result += f.CalcResult(distSq[count], i, j);
            count++;
         }
      }
      return result;
   }
   double DoTest2()
   {
      double result = 0;
      for (uint i=0; i<c.count; i++)
         for (uint j=i; j<c.count; j++)
            result += f.CalcResult(c.GetDist(i,j), i, j);
      return result;
   }
}
```

Will `Test` automatically enable parallelism (e.g. vectorized math or improved memory access) on x86 chips, given its repetitive operations on a single data set?

Otherwise `Test` is a garbage approach -- it uses extra storage (the `std::vector<double> distSq;`) and is much longer in terms of code reading.  Logically it's more or less identical, however if we call `GetDist` `f_A` (function A) and `CalcResult` `f_B` (function B), Test is:

```
f_A f_A f_A ... f_A    f_B f_B .... f_B
```

Where as the shorter/less memory intensive function is

```
f_A f_B f_A f_B .... f_A f_B
```

I've heard talk of so-called "inherent parallelism" in `-O#` compiled C-codes due to generated vectorized math ops, etc.  Could `Test` enable such compiler-derived parallelism (e.g. vectorized math or optimized memory access?) on x86 chips, given its repetitive operations on a single data set?

(Otherwise `Test2` is the only reasonable approach as it uses less memory.)

Also would replacing the c-style `x`, `y`, and `z` arrays with `std::vector<double>` alternatives have the possibility to accelerate the computations or memory access in any way?

Please don't answer "Benchmark yourself" ... the reason I'm asking to try to gain a better understanding as to whether it's worth testing approach `Test` via benchmarking from a THEORETICAL perspective, based on a compilers and "inherent parallelism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory access will kill you regardless of parallelism. There's a small improvement where you call `.reserve(c.count*c.count())` to prevent reallocations in `.push_back`, but that's not enough. If `c.count` is large enough to matter, this will waste the L1 cache and possible L2.

The next problem is that your `f_A` function depends on a memory access. A modern processor can issue that read and work on a previous `f_B` in the mean time. There are no data dependencies. That makes `Test2` even more efficient.

BYW, is it just me, or are CalcResult(i,j) and CalcResult(j,i) very similar? You might benefit from combining the calculations.

I would make `A` and `B` `double const*`. You're not writing through them, after all.

What might work well is a `#pragma omp for reduction(+, result)`.

Comment: MSalters, they are the same, actually.  That's why I start the inner loop @ j --- it's a calculation on unique coordinate pairs, so we only calculate half the N * N coordinate space... good thoughts on the memory access, thanks... that's what I was thinking... I'll probably start with the f_A f_B ... approach

Comment: Right, overlooked that bit - you would need to reserve only (N*N+N)/2 elements in that case. Still O(N*N) memory accesses.

Answer (score 1):

**Classic SIMD compiler optimization**

A simple example of code known to be easy to optimize with SIMD instructions by the compiler is the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
     C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
```

[SIMD optimization example with VC++](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/10/17/simd-optimized-c-code-in-visual-studio-11.aspx)

**In your case**

Your first loop with `c.GetDist` does look like all the iterations are independent from one another, but depending on what `GetDist` really does, combined with pushing back the result into a vector, I think it could be harder for the compiler to generate SIMD instructions than what is the case with simply adding 2 vectors in built-in arrays. I'm no compiler expert, though, so I could be wrong. It can vary from compiler to compiler as well.

The best way to know for sure is to compile your code and look at the disassembly to see what kind of instructions were generated by your compiler. For example, if you are on IA-32 or 64 bit Intel, look for instructions that act on the MMX or XMM registers. You could also try replacing the vector with a built-in array to see if it makes any difference.

[Intel assembly language reference](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf)

**An interesting talk**

I recently watched an interesting talk by Jim Radigan at the Going Native 2013 conference. He works on the Microsoft C++ compiler backend team and specializes in code optimization. He touched on several interesting topics among which was achieving parallelism in the generated machine code. Here is the link of the talk:

[Jim Radigan talks about compiler optimization](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Compilerpp-)